# Cannot uninstall java on Mac

Tags: java, uninstall, jdk, jre

I want to downgrade from java 9 to java 8 on my mac (MacOSX High Sierra (Version 10.13.2))

I find the same instructions regarding how to do this everywere everywhere (including on the [java site](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml)):

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Java
```

While this successfully removes the files and folder in question, and I can then install JDK8, if I run `java -version`, I still get:

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Which means that java 9 is still there despite following the uninstall steps. How can I get rid of java 9.0.1?

Comment: You failed to indicate the version of the OS you are using.  Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Thanks. I added my OS version (there is only one question though).

Comment: I just copied the close reason. The important part of that comment was, “Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.”, the second sentence didn’t necessarily apply to your question but is the standard reason for “too broad”

Comment: I really don't know how this question could be more precise. I give the problem, the environment, the exact steps followed and the failed outcome.

Comment: Your missing a [step](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html)

Comment: The 'Internet Plug-ins' location in your `rm` is for the Java JRE. The JDK installs in somewhere like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk`